# Functional equation $f(x)f(f(x))=x^2$

Tags: functions, functional-equations

Find all real functions such that
$f(x)f(f(x))=x^2$ and $f(x)=x$ for some $x$.

Obviously $f(x)=x$ is a solution, but I have no clue how to find other solutions.

Comment: There is nothing to link $f(x_1)$ and $f(x_2)$ in this equation, so I doubt you can get very far...

Comment: The equation already forces f(0)=0. Other than that, for every $x, y\in\mathbb R$ with $x, y\neq 0$, there is always a solution with $f(x) = y$ (the equation then gives the values of $f^{n}(x)$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$ and we can just set $f(z)=z$ for every other value of $z$).

Comment: Without further assumptions (e.g. continuity), there are way too many solutions to have a reasonable hope of describing all of them explicitly.

Comment: @TippingOctopus: I don't think that's quite right; for some values of $x$ and $y$ there will be repeats among the values of $f^n(x)$ which could give a contradiction.  It will be true if, say, $x$ and $y$ are algebraically independent.

Comment: @EricWofsey I think you can explicitly write down the sequence and if my calculation is correct, there won't be repeats unless $x=\pm y$, but in that case things are trivial

Comment: @TippingOctopus: Oh, I see now.  That's neat.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a whole family of solutions. Let $g(x)$ be any function from the reals to $\{-1,1\}$ such that $g(g(x)x)=1$. Then define $f(x)=g(x)x$. We get

$$f(x)f(f(x))=\left[g(x)x\right]\left[g(g(x)x)\right]\left[g(x)x\right]=g(x)^2x^2\cdot 1=x^2$$

Now, here are some examples of such $g(x)$:

$$g_1(x)=1$$

$$g_2(x)=\begin{cases} 
      1 & x\geq  0 \\
      -1 & x<0
   \end{cases}$$

$$g_3(x)=\begin{cases} 
      1 & x\leq   0 \\
      -1 & x>0
   \end{cases}$$

(it is easy to prove that these all work). Now, let $A$ and $B$ be any sets such that

$$A\cup B=\mathbb{R}$$

$$A\cap B=\emptyset$$

$$a\in A\Rightarrow -a\in A$$

$$b\in B\Rightarrow -b\in B$$

We may finally get to the punchline: For such $A$ and $B$, the function

$$g(x)=\begin{cases} 
      g_i(x) & x\in A \\
      g_j(x) & x\in B
   \end{cases}$$

(where $i$ and $j$ are selected from $\{1,2,3\}$) is another valid $g(x)$. The proof is simple: note that for $x\in A$ we have

$$g_i(x)x\in\{x,-x\}$$

This implies $g_i(x)x\in A$. Therefore

$$g(g_i(x)x)=g_i(g_i(x)x))=1$$

(the same logic applies to $B$). We conclude if $A$ and $B$ follow the conditions above, then $f(x)f(f(x))=x^2$ where $f(x)=g(x)x$ and $g(x)$ is as defined above (for any choice of $i$ and $j$).

Answer (score 0):

Or solutions of the form : $f(x)=ax^b$

Substitutin gives $f(x)=x,\frac{1}{x^2}$